# Excute an application which works with versions.

Tags: c#, winforms, process, publishing, asp.net-4.5

Good day,

Currently i'm working on a simple code where I want to start a new application by using the fallowing code:

```
            ProcessInfo.FileName = @"T:\APP.exe";
            ProcessInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
            ProcessInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            ProcessInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Maximized;
            ProcessInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;
            ProcessInfo.UseShellExecute = false;  

            Process proc = Process.Start(ProcessInfo);
```

The "APP" which I want to start is being updated regularly. Each version is installed in the APPDATA file. Unfortunately for each version I publish with Visual Studio gives an unique id to the folder location, for example:

Local\Apps\2.0\YCAL8JOR.XMP\WLOTE7VA.1D9\cond..tion_6757f2505ca8bd82_0001.0000_fee986f0f10e782c

for this reason my 'ProcessInfo.FileName' will always be different. Is there some kind of method that will give me dynamic access to my application so that i can keep updating my application without having to change the filepath in this function for each time?

(i'm still new at programming, exuse me for my ignorance)

Comment: If your using ClickOnce to publish your app this could be the solution http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/xctb6ae4.aspx

Comment: if the Application runs in the same directory `System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location`

Comment: @PaulZahra i'm using the publish wizard of visual studio 2013, i'm not sure if that's the ClickOnce method. :)

Comment: Use a registry entry to track your install path. I would write some code for you and submit as an answer, but I'm on my mobile.

Comment: Thank you for that suggestion @Tim. I've looked up the key, and I see there are quite alot of those keys. 

If you could share some code with me, that would be great!

Comment: @Nieksa Have you tried the article example?

Comment: I'm not sure to what article you are refering to

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can do this In two ways

1. we can try having a a custom action on the installer that actually writes the Installed Path to Registry with a specific key
   And your code to read the registry to get the path and Execute it.
2. The other way is you get the Files From the parent Directory ( I mean till the Directory you are Sure that this will get Installed) Sort By the Creation date and the match your Exe name and take the Latest one and Start the Process.

Option #2 will not work if user can choose the Installation path. I suggest to go with Option #1

Comment: I'm not sure yet how to tackel option 1, but I'll try :)

Comment: @Nieksa following links may give you some Idea how to achieve that  https://www.simple-talk.com/dotnet/visual-studio/getting-started-with-setup-projects/            https://www.simple-talk.com/dotnet/visual-studio/visual-studio-setup---projects-and-custom-actions/